# Remove update elements from User-Defined Table Type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, upsert

On a User-Defined Table Type, `@TT dbo.IntType readonly,`,
`IntType` is batch of `int`, as Primary-Key

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntType] AS TABLE(
    [T] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

I would like to do an `UPDATE` based on all key(`int`) in `IntType`, and `INSERT` new rows for the key(`int`) not exist in the database (an upsert). How?

---

I wonder if there is an easy way to remove the "UPDATED" key(`int`)? Then I can insert the rest.
*(or if you have a super one-line upsert for SQL Server)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `MERGE` statement.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Let me see if I can put something together.

EDIT: Example

```
MERGE INTO [TargetTable] AS T
USING (SELECT l.T AS 'id' FROM @list l ) AS S
ON (T.[id] = S.[id])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        T.updated = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES ([insert value into each column of target table]);
```

EDIT 2: The parameter `@list` is the list that is passed in that you populated with the ids

Comment: holy cow, that was easy, I cannot wait to try it

Comment: It is really nice but this only works on 2008 and up. Since you are using 2010 I figured you would be fine.

Comment: It works like a charm, fast and reliable. Worked both on my local `SQL Server 2008 R2` and `SQL Azure`. For the SQL 2010 thing, my fault, M$ has too many products, messed up my mind.

Comment: I wasn't quite too sure what that was either. I figured it was a new release after 2008 R2 but figured I don't always keep up with the latest versions.