# Insert or Update user-defined table type in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on a project where I insert or update a lot of data frequently to a remote database. The data volume is around 50 sets of data with 500-800 rows each, that goes into the same table.

Currently I have a stored procedure that I call for every row to insert or update (simplified for easier read):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE stat_memberstat_upsert
...
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Memberstats ...

if(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Memberstats ...
END
END
```

This works, but as you can see it mounts to a lot of calls to the same stored procedure (worst case around 100,000 calls). I'm looking into User-defined table type, which sound like a good solution, because it decreases the calls to the database server, with a more bulk like structure. The problem is that when I look at the solutions, tutorials and documentations I find that no one mentions a way to do a insert/update routine with the table type; it's either insert or update.

Is there a way, when working with table types, to do a insert/update call?

---

Alternatively I have thought about two workaround solutions:

**1: Using cursor**

I could use a cursor to iterate through the table type value and call the stat_memberstat_upsert procedure above for each row. This will not prevent the many calls to the procedure, but since the calls are done from a local stored procedure the speed might increase.

[How to do ForEach on user defined table type in SQL Server stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774488/how-to-do-foreach-on-user-defined-table-type-in-sql-server-stored-procedure) (answer "Why not use a cursor ???")

**2: Pre validate data**

Second solution is to retrieve the already inserted rows primary keys, validate them against the incoming data and sort them into 2 tables, where one is for inserts and the other one is for updates. Then execute both tables to the database. This means that I need to encapsulate this in a transaction so the table will not change during the time is take to validate and execute the insert and update.

Would any of these be a good solution?

Comment: I'm not sure where you've been looking where you get the impression that you can only insert or update, but have you looked into [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I never heard about merge. Thanks for the tip; i'm currently checking to see if I can make it work with Merge

Comment: Also, may be out of your scope, but this sounds like something that might be better implemented as an SSIS package?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are a life saver. The MERGE works well with  table types and the speed is now incredible. Thank you! Could you create an answer so we can close this up?

Answer (score 0):

Both the solution might slow down further. 
You can simply have insert statements into a table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE stat_memberstat_upsert
...
AS
INSERT INTO Memberstats_temp ...
END
```

and  have a batch process which will run at low traffic time to update/insert the Memberstats table from Memberstats_temp table after that truncating this temp table. This wouldn't be a solution if you need real time update to the table.